# Confusion with the output of the function str

Tags: r, logistic-regression

The data set `birth.csv` collected at the Baystate Medical Center, Springﬁeld, USA during 1986 has the following format

[image]

After I imported the csv file (using `read.csv()` with `colClasses` specification), the output of the function `str()` didn't match with that of the function `head()`. For example, the first 6 values of the column `low` were supposed to be **0** but the output sample generated by `str()` showed they were **1**

```
'data.frame':   189 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ low  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  # shouldn't they be 0 0 0 0... instead?
 $ age  : num  19 33 20 21 18 21 22 17 29 26 ...
 $ lwt  : num  182 155 105 108 107 124 118 103 123 113 ...
 $ race : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ smoke: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ ptl  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ht   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ui   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ftv  : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 3 2 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...

A data.frame: 6 × 9
    low age lwt race smoke  ptl ht  ui  ftv
    <fct><dbl><dbl><fct><fct><fct><fct><fct><fct>
1   0   19  182 2    0      0   0   1   0
2   0   33  155 3    0      0   0   0   2
3   0   20  105 1    1      0   0   0   1
4   0   21  108 1    1      0   0   1   2
5   0   18  107 1    1      0   0   1   0
6   0   21  124 3    0      0   0   0   0
```

Could someone please explain what happened? If I built a logistic model for that imported dataset, would the result be wrong?

Comment: The levels of the factor were 0 and 1 (as characters). So a numeric 1 indicates “0” and numeric 2 indicates “1”.

Comment: Factors (categorical variables, `<fct>` in the tibble column class) in R are stored internally as integers with `1` being the first level (or category), `2` the second level, etc., along with a lookup table mapping the integer levels to their labels. `str()` doesn't bother with the labels, just uses the integers. Most other functions print the labels, not the integer levels.

Comment: For a somewhat clearer example, run `x = factor(c("a", "b", "a", "c"))` and compare `str(x)` to `x`. It's extra confusing in your case because your labels are (character-class) integers starting at 0.

Comment: And no, a logistic model run on this data will not be wrong - for categorical variables you should be using a `factor` like you have it.

Comment: Thanks, @GregorThomas for your detailed explanation. R syntax and output are certainly confusing (for me at least).

Comment: @GregorThomas please post as an answer, or let's close the post as "read the manuals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors (categorical variables, `<fct>` in the tibble column class labels) in R are stored internally as integers with `1` being the first level (or category), `2` the second level, etc., along with a lookup table mapping the integer values to their labels/levels.

`str()` a few of the levels and then the integer values. Most other functions print the labels, not the integer values.

It's extra confusing in your case because your labels are (character-class) integers starting at 0. For a somewhat clearer example, let's look at a factor with letters as the labels

```
x = factor(c("a", "b", "a", "c"))

x
# [1] a b a c
# Levels: a b c

str(x)
# Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 1 3
```